# Liquibase ChangeLog and LogLock table creation on Later stage without failing already executed scripts

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, liquibase

I have one ***micro-service*** running from long however few days back we realised that **custom** `changelog` and `changeloglock` tables were defined **incorrectly**. See below...

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        abc:
            change-log: classpath:/liquibase/changelog.yml
            database-change-log-table: CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG
            database-change-log-lock-table: CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG_LOCK
```

**`abc`** is added between the correct path and we have almost **18 scripts** already executed which is already logged in master tables `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` .

So if I correct the path in yml per below

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        change-log: classpath:/liquibase/changelog.yml
        database-change-log-table: CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG
        database-change-log-lock-table: CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG_LOCK
```

Then it will go on and execute all old 18 scripts which will lead to failure. **How to get that resolved?**

Also, I am not certain if it will create custom tables automatically or I need to create those manually?

Any help for `both the points` would be appreciated. comment if you need any further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved. There are 2 ways to do this w/o running any manual script. But I preferred below one

We will ***not enter any custom table*** in `application.yml` but will add a new query in changelog.

`changeset` will look something like this

```
- changeSet:
      id: your-id-here
      author: kunal-vohra
      #dbms: oracle #if you want it to run db specific then uncomment
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            encoding: utf8
            path: ./liquibase/changes/sql-file-name.sql
```

And `sql-file-name.sql` will look something like

```
declare
begin
  execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG AS SELECT * FROM DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE AUTHOR = ''kunal-vohra''';
  exception when others then
    if SQLCODE = -955 then null; else raise; end if;
    UPDATE CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG  SET MD5SUM = null;
end;
/
```

What happening in above query is, if table is already created then it will not create the new table otherwise it will.

And then it is dropping all `**HASH**`.

Then raise a 2nd PR  with change in `application.yml`

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        change-log: classpath:/liquibase/changelog.yml
        database-change-log-table: CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG
        database-change-log-lock-table: CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG_LOCK
```

**Major benefit we have here is we don't have to run any thing manually on PROD.**

If you want to do the above in one PR **other way is** just move the `changeset` to top of the file instead of below.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly there are two options:

1. Write `preConditions` to your existing changeSets and specify onFail="MARK_RAN" attribute. This way, all your changeSets will fail on `preConditions` and will be marked as RAN in the `CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG` table. Your application will start successfully.
2. Specify `CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG` table and copy all the data from `databasechangelog`.

ChangeSet for copying data from table to table may look like this:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <tableExists tableName="databasechangelog"/>
        <tableExists tableName="CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG"/>
        <sqlCheck expecterResult="0">
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM databasechangelog; 
        </sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, EXECTYPE, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, TAG, LIQUIBASE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, DEPLOYMENT_ID)
        SELECT ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, EXECTYPE, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, TAG, LIQUIBASE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, DEPLOYMENT_ID
        FROM databasechangelog
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

This changeSet should be the first to be executed when the application starts. So you should put this changeSet before all the other changeSets in your changeLog. After copying all the data, liquibase should treat all your existing changeSets like they've already been executed.

---

I'd use the option #1 since your changeSets should have preConditions anyway.

Comment: how about the new table name. this is yet to be created.

Comment: also you added a dummy queries in SQL. I cant add sqlCheck as all files already ran has big queries. Like 100 rows each. How can I expectResult in such case

Comment: As far as I know, liquibase is supposed to create CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG table itself, as it was specified in property `database-change-log-table: CUSTOM_CHANGE_LOG`, so you don't have to create it yourself.
And to answer your second comment - unfortunately, it could be the case when you may either skip preConditions, or make them enormously huge. I guess you may skip writing them and use the second approach.

Comment: Nope. That will leads to build failure. Tried.

Comment: my understanding mistake maybe. What I undrstood in 2nd approach is I create my own table before and pull data from DATABASECHANGELOG table. COrrect?

Comment: Correct. You provide a new name of `databasechangelog` table. Liquibase will create it itself (I've just checked it on local environment). Just put the changeSet I've provided at the very beginning of your changeLog. You need this changeSet to be executed before all the others.

Comment: Upvote for your efforts. Let me try to find a bit documented way.